# How to show virtual keypad in an android activity

Tags: android

Why am i not able to show the virtual keyboard in my activity. Here is my code:

package som.android.keypad;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ShowKeypad extends Activity {
    InputMethodManager imm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle); 
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText);

    ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(editText, 0); 



    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="som.android.keypad"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".ShowKeypad"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"  
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Checkout my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289335/soft-keyboard-shows-up-on-edittext-focus-only-once/7291121#7291121

Comment: your problem is solve or not?

Answer (score 7):

**First setContentView**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Sometime in `android 4.2 keyboard` **not automatically open**.

You have to used this way to **open and close** keyboard programmatically.

```
//For open keyboard
public void OpenKeyBoard(Context mContext){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
    }
    //For close keyboard
    public void CloseKeyBoard(Context mContext){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY,0);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you boss. you save my time :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

seems to be missing. Manifest setting should be enough to show keyboard