# calling the Android soft keyboard from a C++ file

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am facing some issues in calling the Android soft keyboard from a C++ file. I have a project in C++ and I need to show and use the native soft keyboard in some screens. I am compiling all the code with NDK.
Can anybody provide a suggestion on how to use the soft keyboard in a native / C++ application ?
Thanks in advance for your help.
Regards,
Maidul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Create a method in Java to show the virtual keyboard like this: [How to show virtual keypad in an android activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722896/how-to-show-virtual-keypad-in-an-android-activity)

2) Write a callback from C++ to Java using the following technique:
[JNI - How to callback from C++ or C to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630134/jni-how-to-callback-from-c-or-c-to-java)

Answer (score -4):

you can't use only the C++ for an Android application, you can build an app using the C++ or the C through the JNI and Java. All the Apis provided for Android are for the Java language.

Comment: Hello user827992,My apps is in NDK means it is using SDK,JNI,Java and C++ and some resource file.resource file save in sd card and written in xml and access through c++. when app is running there is a page and page contains edit text.When I touch Edit Text it will open Android Native soft keyboard.Could you please have some idea.

Comment: as per the comment above,there should be no problem in getting the soft keyboard when u r clicking over textbox.